# Using a "request.method" statement inside a "while" (Flask)

Tags: python, flask, logic

I'm having a problem developing the loop by conditional statement. The systems asks me infinitely times for data, not respecting the "x" value. I want to repeat de interface "x" times and then return the total result called "EF". Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, session

app = Flask(__name__) #create the Flask app
app.secret_key = "hello"

@app.route('/begin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
    x = 2
    i = 1
    EF = int()
    EFT = int()
    while i <= x:

            if request.method == 'POST':
                y1 = request.form['y1']
                session ['y1'] = y1

                EF = EF + int(y1)
                i += 1
                session ['EF'] = EF


            return '''<form method="POST">

            Input y1:        <input type="text" name="y1"><br>

                        <input type="submit" value="Ingresar"><br>

                        <input type="reset" value="Borrar todo"><br>

                        <input type="button" onclick="history.back()" name="back" value="back"><br>

                    </form>'''



    return '''The value is: '''+str(EF)



if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
  app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

Comment: I'd like to hear more about the use case. There must be a better solution than putting a request method inside a while statement. You either make a GET request ( which is default) or you make a POST request. There are lots of ways to add complexity to your code but please not like this.

Comment: Hello! I have a variable named "x" that is input in an interface (That's ok). Then, the next interface will appear "x" times asking me some values ("y" and "z"). After input all the "x" interfaces, the next will show me the total of "y" and "z".

Comment: Bear in mind that a flask web app is stateless. That means, every previous state of a variable is 'reset' to its original state when you call /begin route. If you really want to continue on current code, you could for instance store/update a variable in session with session['my_object'] = x, and call it the other way around with x = session['my_object'].